# Определить что изменись в результате resize: высота или ширина или обе величины?

Tags: jquery

Всем доброго времени суток!

Можно ли как-то красиво (без дополнительных переменных/костылей) определить что изменись в результате resize: высота или ширина или обе величины?

Я вот как делал:

1. Load: объявляю переменные высоты и ширины. Задаю из значения.
2. Resize: получаю новые значения высоты и ширины. Сравниваю. Определяю что изменилось. Переопределяю переменные из пункта 1.

Но как-то мне не очень нравиться такой подход.

Comment: А чем конкретно не нравится такой подход? 

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая, для того, чтоб что-то сравнивать, надо иметь, как минимум, два сопостовляемых свойства. В вашем случае, как ни крути, но это "*было до*" и "*стало после*" или "*было до*" и "*изменяется в процессе*". Так что не вижу ничего странного в том, как это реализовано у вас сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйте [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

```
variableName.addEventListener('change', functionName, false);
```

где `variableName` - переменная, за изменением значения которой нужно следить,
`functionName` - имя хэндлера изменения.